# Cells(1,#) vs Cells(1,@)

Tags: excel, vba

Is it faster/better practice when using Cells to refer to the column part with a number or a letter?

Aside from the obvious points that using the letter makes the code easier to read when you're using higher numbered columns, and using the number allows easier looping, are there any benefits/drawbacks to one over the other?

Comment: Both work, both are documented. I vastly prefer numbers over strings, but that's largely a matter of taste.

Comment: If you want to know which is faster, set up a test to compare a large number of repeats of one against the same number of repeats of the other.  I would guess the times are the same with literals since I would expect the compiler to convert to whichever format the interpreter prefers.

Comment: I set up a test and found that there is no performance advantage to one over the other.  Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

It is a matter of personal preference.  You can easily loop *(even with letters)*

```
Sub LoopLetters()
    Dim letter As Variant
    For Each letter In Array("A", "B", "C", "D")
        MsgBox Cells(1, letter).Value
    Next letter
End Sub
```